# Ordenar columnas en jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

Como puedo ordenar mi JqGrid de acuerdo a la columna NumUnidad

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo:

```
$("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
                url: URLTemario + id,
                mtype: "GET",
                datatype: "json",
                colModel: [
                    { label: 'Id', name: 'IdReg', key: true, width: 70, hidden: true },
                    { label: 'IdMateria', name: 'IdMateria', width: '60', hidden: true },
                    { label: 'Relacion', name: 'Relacion', width: '60', hidden: true },
                    { label: 'Unidad', name: 'NumUnidad', width: '60' },
                    { label: 'Tema', name: 'Descripcion', width: '300' }
                ],
                sortname: 'IdReg',
                loadonce: true,
                height: 'auto',
                rowNum: 10,
                pager: "#jqGridPager",
                width: '100%',
                caption: "REGISTROS",
                viewrecords: true,
});
```

En NumUnidad recibo un conjunto de valores como por ejemplo:

NumUnidad = 1,
NumUnidad = 2,
NumUnidad = 1.1
NumUnidad = 1.2
NumUnidad = 2.1

Entonces los quiero ordenar de forma ascendente en mi tabla por NumUnidad (Número de Unidad de un asignatura o materia)

Comment: Por favor, no publiques una imagen del código, publica el código mismo utilizando el [resaltado de sintaxis para código](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting)

Answer (score 1):

Hola bueno primero que nada es cierto te tienes que apoyar de:

```
sortname: "NumUnidad",
sortorder: "asc",
```

Estas variables las manda en automático por `GET` por lo cual lo puedes recibir en tu archivo de consulta, suponiendo que uses `PHP` las recibes de la siguiente manera:

```
$sortname = $_GET['sortname']; 
$sortorder = $_GET['sortorder'];
```

Con esto ya puedes utilizarlas en la parte donde hagas tu consulta:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Registros ORDER BY $sortname '$sortorder'";
```

El valor que defines en la creación de tu Grid es el que tomara al momento de cargar, en cuanto el usuario clickea sobre otrs columna puede cambiar el valor por el de esa columna y manda el valor name de la columna clickeada así como el ordenamiento ascendente o descendente.

OJO los `name:` de tu grid deben de tener el mismo nombre que los campos en tu tabla.

Answer (score 0):

No tengo mucha idea de que parámetros reciba la tabla pero he investigado un poco y he dado con esto:

```
sortname: "NumUnidad",
sortorder: "asc",
```

Donde `sortname` es el campo a ordenar por defecto.

Y también `sortorder` que sera la manera en que se mostraran `asc` o `desc` en tu caso creo que sera `asc`, aunque en la [documentación](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) dice que esta por defecto `asc`.

Entonces tu código quedaría:

```
$("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
    url: URLTemario + id,
    mtype: "GET",
    datatype: "json",
    colModel: [
      { label: 'Id', name: 'IdReg', key: true, width: 70, hidden: true },
      { label: 'IdMateria', name: 'IdMateria', width: '60', hidden: true },
      { label: 'Relacion', name: 'Relacion', width: '60', hidden: true },
      { label: 'Unidad', name: 'NumUnidad', width: '60' },
      { label: 'Tema', name: 'Descripcion', width: '300' }
    ],
    sortname: 'NumUnidad',
    sortorder: "asc",
    loadonce: true,
    height: 'auto',
    rowNum: 10,
    pager: "#jqGridPager",
    width: '100%',
    caption: "REGISTROS",
    viewrecords: true,
});
```